# Google maps directions from A to B considering traffic

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to get google maps directions from A to B with considering traffic at the moment of calling the function?

This code below works fine if it is empty road:

```
var gm = require("googlemaps");

gm.directions("from", "where go to" , function ( err, data ) {
    console.log(data.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
    console.log(data.routes[0].legs[0].duration);
}, "false");
```

I am new to google maps, so please any thought to spare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) gives you a clear answer:

*durationInTraffic (optional) specifies whether the DirectionsLeg result should include a duration that takes into account current traffic conditions. This feature is **only available for Maps for Business customers**. The time in current traffic will only be returned if traffic information is available in the requested area.*

Comment: this not the answer I hoped for. but TY